# One-line anonymous method

Tags: c#

I have a question. Consider that scenerio:

```
    public override string Encrypt(string input)
    { 
        Func<char, char> encryption = (c) => (char)chars[(c * k1 + k0) % 26]; 

        string result = string.Empty;
        foreach(char c in input)
            result += encryption(c);

        return result;
    }
```

My question is, can we change that `result += encryption(c)` line into something like in `Func<char, char>` declaration? Can we write this anonymous method in *one line*?

Comment: `result = string.Concat(input.Select(c => encryption(c)));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using *Linq*, i. e.

```
public override string Encrypt(string input)
{ 
    Func<char, char> encryption = (c) => (char)chars[(c * k1 + k0) % 26]; 

    return string.Concat(input.Select(c => encryption(c)));
}
```

We can even get rid of `encryption`:

```
public override string Encrypt(string input) => 
   string.Concat(input.Select(c => (char)chars[(c * k1 + k0) % 26]));
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain, why we need `string.Concat`, why we get exception when we want just use `input.Select()`? What kind of logic is behind this line?

Comment: And is this way is not too much functional-programming way? Can we use it in OOP?

Comment: `string.Concat` convert `IEnumerable<char>` which is returned by `Select` into `string`. When querying with *Linq* we work with `IEnumerable<T>`, in case of `string` we treat it as `IEnunerable<char>` (sequence of characters) which we finally want to *materialize* as `string`

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
result = string.Concat(input.Select(c => encryption(c)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Not that it's very readable, but here is whole method simplified to one line:

```
public override string Encrypt(string input) => string.Concat(input.Select(c => (char)chars[(c * k1 + k0) % 26]));
```